# Nvidia Jetson GPIO with ROS

Tags: ros, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are plenty of articles online about the [Jetson GPIO](http://elinux.org/Jetson/GPIO) but there's not much about using it with ROS.

Is there a simple way to integrate Jetson GPIO with ROS or do you have to control everything manually through your ROS cpp program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238065/nvidia-jetson-gpio-with-ros/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-06-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do it both ways. You can directly access the pins from your program with C++. The other approach is to write a node that uses topics or services to access or set the pins. For reference you can look at these resources from the wiki:

[Writing a Simple Service and Client (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B))

[Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B))

I don't know how you are managing permissions on your robot, but for me to access GPIO on my Beaglebone, I just made sudo passwordless and then when my node launched, I chmodded the /dev/class/gpio folder to allow my user to access it.
Hope this helps!
luketheduke

---

Originally posted by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) with karma: 285 on 2016-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-06-26**:
Great info! I'm glad you brought up permissions. I think I'll take your passwordless sudo approach. I have wifi / ssh on this machine but sudo won't apply unless someone is logged in so I should be good.

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-06-26**:
Also, another thing to note is that if you are using the `robot_upstart` package to launch your nodes on boot, then you want to modify the source code for it to use `sudo -u USERNAME` instead of the `setuid` that it uses itself. In the unmodified state, `robot_upstart` doesn't play nice with GPIO.

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-06-26**:
If this answer answers your question, please mark it solved by pressing the button below the upvote/downvote buttons. This helps improve the ROS community.
Thanks,
luketheduke

**Comment by [CoachAllen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50863/coachallen/) on 2020-01-15**:
Is there an include statement for GPIO in C++? Like #include /jetson/gpio

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2020-01-15**:
There are several different approaches to controlling GPIO with the Jetson. Because C++ is such a low level language here is the recommended approach from the Nvidia forums: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1052379/jetson-nano/how-to-use-gpio-in-c-language/post/5342398/#5342398 You can also try this library: https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod

**Comment by [CoachAllen](https://answers.ros.org/users/50863/coachallen/) on 2020-01-26**:
So you would merely make the gpio availble to any package calling it?

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2020-04-20**:
It depends on what approach you want to take, you could either integrate GPIO into every package that needed it or make one package that handles all GPIO and communicates over a topic/service.